# How does quantum dynamics explain interference of two light beams

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am a new learner of quantum dynamics. I am puzzled about this. As quantum mechanics implies that photon can only interfere with itself, so what did photons from one light beam do to photons from another to cause the interference? (Photons from different light beams are in the same state and can not be distinguished when interference happens?)

Comment: This experiment works with single emitted photons too. And it works also for single edges. Last not least somehow the edge's electrons have to interact with the photons. It is time to overthink the interference idea.